# How to check if Firebase updated remotely?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, firebase, angularfire

I have an app that uses AngularJS and Firebase (with AngularFire API), but I'm getting some problems with the $bindTo service. Sometimes users are loosing data because there is no good connection in my city, our internet is too slow. I was thinking to create an icon in my app that shows the user if its data was updated successfully or not.

How I was thinking to do it?
 - Watch the object
 - On data changed, the icon becomes red
 - When data is saved on Firebase, returns an event that change the icon color to green

How can I do it? Is there a better way to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html
This gives example of how to check out connection status and event handlers to deal with such situations .

Comment: I found this page before asking here, but I couldn't find an answer. It shows ways to check internet connection and do some thinks (like update and remove data) when user is disconnected, but what I was looking for is something to really tell me if data was synchronised successfully. Do you know something else that could help me?

Comment: You may prefer to use $save which returns a promise when save is completed.                                                                                           e.g.                                                                                                        var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);  
obj.foo = "bar";  
obj.$save().then(function(ref) {  
  ref.key() === obj.$id; // true  
}, function(error) {  
  console.log("Error:", error);  
});

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to keep using $bindTo, but I see that I have no choice now. =)